# Create a line graph with gradients in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, gradient, uibezierpath, cagradientlayer

What's the best way to create a graph like this in iOS?

[image]

My first thought was to create a bezier path and then add a gradient layer with the different locations. But this can't work since the documentation specifies that:

> The values must be monotonically increasing.

Which is not the case in my graph.

Any thoughts on good ways to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: What does the gradient color signify? It doesn't seem to vary with the x or y value of the chart. Is it a third dimension of data?

Comment: @jrturton no, the color data is the same as the Y axis value. The image is done by the designer so it's not really representative of how the data and visual will actually look like.

Comment: @JoanCardona - *"it's not really representative"* ... if you want help on how to "do something," you'll be much better off showing exactly what you want to do. Posting an image that ***doesn't*** look like what you want isn't really very helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by using a `CAGradientLayer` as the background of your chart, and then a `CAShapeLayer` as a mask of the gradient layer. The mask layer will only show the layer beneath in areas that it is drawn on.

This playground code gives a general idea, using randomly generated data:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))
view.backgroundColor = .black

// Gradient for the chart colors
let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
gradient.colors = [
    UIColor.red.cgColor,
    UIColor.orange.cgColor,
    UIColor.yellow.cgColor,
    UIColor.green.cgColor
]
gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)

gradient.frame = view.bounds
view.layer.addSublayer(gradient)

// Random points
let graph = CAShapeLayer()
let path = CGMutablePath()
var y: CGFloat = 150
let points: [CGPoint] = stride(from: CGFloat.zero, to: 300, by: 2).map {
    let change = CGFloat.random(in: -20...20)
    var newY = y + change
    newY = max(10, newY)
    newY = min(newY, 300)
    y = newY
    return CGPoint(x: $0, y: y)
}
path.addLines(between: points)
graph.path = path
graph.fillColor = nil
graph.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
graph.lineWidth = 4
graph.lineJoin = .round
graph.frame = view.bounds

// Only show the gradient where the line is
gradient.mask = graph

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: This is amazing, exactly what I needed and a lot easier than what I was developing. Thank you.